# React: To what extend should I use Context API? Why not use a separate JS file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-context

I'm new to React and my goal is to create a PWA. I learned about Context API and Redux, that can be used to store, for example, user data. But why should I use them and until what extend?

When the user enters the app, I want all the data to be requested to the server and then stored in the context API, so that it could be accessed anywhere and changed if necessary.

But I read that react context re-renders all the components when the data is changed. I thought about Redux but I think it could be a little bit complex or it could harm performance.

The data would be something like:

```
user: {
    information: {
         name, lastName,...
    }
    profilePic: ....,//updated if user changes picture
    email, position
}
friends: [{
   id, name, lastname, profilePic //state updated if the user adds a friend 
}]
notifications: [{
   seen, header, content, redirectId //state updated if a new notification comes 
}]
//The actual data would be more than this
```

And I haven't stopped thinking about why not use a separate file? Such as:

```
class data {
   constructor(){
   userData = {}
   friends = []
   notifications = []
    axios.get("/userData").then(res=>{
       userData = res.userData;
       friends = res.friends;
       notifications = res.notifications;
    })
   }
   
   update(data){
     axios.post("/userData", {data}).then(res=>{
       userData = res.userData;
       friends = res.friends;
       notifications = res.notifications;
     })
   }

   get(){
      return {userData: this.userData, friends: this.friends, notifications: this.notifications} 
   }
 
}
export default new Data()
```

I tested it and it returns the information even if it is changed.

What is the more efficient way and which should I use considering that when a user changes to some page or press a button that returns data, that specific data will update from a server request if necessary?

Comment: Okay, how would you trigger components to be re-rendered with this approach? What if you have components at many different levels/location that you need to ensure have been re-rendered with new data? You may need to add specifically how your components are structured to help provide better guidance. You can definitely not use context or redux, but also it may make things easier.

Comment: We were definitely successful with your approach. It might not be worst thing to get started with something simple, and start considering more complex approaches when you run into limitations.